# P wave to S wave conversion

Tags: geophysics, seismology, waves

While passing through layers inside the earth some P waves get converted to S waves and then back to P waves while returning towards the surface. Is this statement true?

If yes, then why? (Considering that they are both fundamentally different in terms of wave theory - longitudinal vs. transverse)

Answer (score 16):

P and S waves are fundamentally different, when it comes to properties of the wave. An example might be that [P waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-wave) can travel through fluids while S waves cannot. However, when it comes down to wave theory, these two are just different polarizations of a [mechanical wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_wave).

#### Seismology

In seismics this concept may be puzzling as we make some very fundamental assumptions. However, seismologists are very well aware that these polarizations (they call them *phases*) usually change throughout their travelpath. When you look at the image below, you can see different travelpaths and the same source will trigger P and S waves. This P wave will travel to the point P where it can be recorded as direct P wave. Upon reflection it will be partially converted to a S wave, which you can also see on the nomination PP is the P part of the reflected P wave and PS is the S part of the reflected and converted P wave. (Actually you can go on happily converting back and forth.)

[image: Travelpaths of waves after EQ]

#### Seismics

In seismics we get this conversion on interfaces or layer boundaries (whichever name you use). So everytime a wave is reflected it may also be partially converted into a different polarization. So essentially, your statement is wrong. The wave doesn't just convert passing through a layer, it is converted upon interaction with an interface. 
So while this wasn't a yes directly to your question let me elaborate why this conversion happens.

[image: Reflectivity of PP and PS conversions at an interface - Source: Crewes.org]

This picture basically shows the rate of conversion depending on the incident angle. At 30° the rate of conversion is maximized. (The scales are terrible to read sorry.) At this interface we can see the incident wave as excitor of a new wave package. So we have to take a detour into wave excitation.

#### Exctiting waves

In marine seismics we can excite pure P waves, because we're operating in a fluid. On land you will always excite a mix of P and S waves (and variations thereupon, namely surface waves). The excitation of these waves is direction dependent. Starting a P wave in one direction will always start an S wave component perpendicular to this direction. Of course we have some energy distribution so that we get something like this:

[image: Daghero, Dario, et al. "Strong-coupling d-wave superconductivity in PuCoGa5 probed by point-contact spectroscopy." Nature communications 3 (2012): 786.]

P waves in the **+** direction and S waves in the **-** direction. (This image was vor conductivity but it serves the point.)

#### At the interface

We have to look at the incident wave as an excitor at the interface, which will give us a P and a S wave response. In seismics, [wave theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_mechanism) and other solutions you can usually see the S wave solution stands perpendicular on a P wave solution (except when we're dealing with anisotropy). So yes in the end your incident wave will start two P waves and two S waves that look like this:

[image: Crewes.org]